# Vue file data is not showing in Blade Template

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Vue file data is not showing in Blade Template.
Error Comes in console is:

> Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

I build a vue file and try to display data of vue in blade bt it not showing help me.

this is my main js file `app.js`

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.component('chat-form-component', require('./components/ChatFormComponent.vue').default);
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(App)
})
```

This is the vue file `ChatFormCompnent.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <form class="form">
        <textarea
            cols="25"
            rows="5"
            class="form-input">
        </textarea>
        <span class="notice">
            Hit Return to send a message
        </span>
    </form>
    </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
 }
</script>

<style>
.form {
    padding: 8px;
}
.form-input {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #d3e0e9;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    outline: none;
}
.notice {
    color: #aaa
}

</style>
```

This is the blade template `chat.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Chats</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Chats
                    </div>
                </div>
                <chat-form-component></chat-form-component>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Users</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        Users
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Where is `App` defined for `app.js`?

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/713#issuecomment-250966053

Answer (score 0):

You need to recompile your assets after changes. 
Run one of the following commands

```
npm run watch
npm run watch-poll
```

Also, Please refresh your browser after running commands.

You can further read [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#running-mix).

Answer (score 0):

In this line `render: h => h(App)`, you don't have an `App` component imported. If you are just following the Laravel + Vue scaffolding, it doesn't use an App component so you can just delete that line.

Make sure your layouts.app blade have something like this:

```
<div id="app">
    @yield('content')
</div>
```

Also, run the watch commands as ashish.negi answered.

Comment: yes i check my layout.blade everything is well but still it not working